# Gmail Markup with Mandrill

Tags: email, gmail, markup, mandrill, json-ld

I'm testing the gmail markup "go to action": 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/actions-overview#go-to_actions

I've set up a gmail markup (with microdata due Mandrill doesn't support json-ld) in a HTML email and send it like it's shown in this tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial

It's working well, but when I try to send the same HTML email through Mandrill API, the action button is not shown at all. I know the "from" and "to" emails must be the same gmail account so I do so when I send it in both cases, but just only works when I use the app script.

Is mandrill removing any microdata info when the email is sent? Has anyone dealt with this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Your mails [need to be authenticated via DKIM or SPF](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google#email_sender_quality_guidelines). The app-script (and Gmail in general) does this automatically for you. It thus probably won't work with Mandrill unless you [register with Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google).

Comment: Not really. According Google documentation (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/testing-your-schema). They say that all emails where the sender and the recipient are the same account ignore the registration requirements and can be used for self-testing.

Anyway, I've set up the DKIM and SPF authentication in Mandrill before testing gmail markups. So, definitely that's not the problem.